# Do an operation every 100ms for 1000 ms

Tags: android

I would like to do an operation every 100ms for 1000ms.

I believe I would need to use the

```
handler
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Timer t = new Timer();
int count = 0;
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    count++;
    // Do stuff
    if (count >= 10)
        t.cancel();
}, 0, 100);
```

This schedules a timer to execute a `TimerTask`, with a 0 millisecond delay.  It will execute the body of the `TimerTask` every 100 milliseconds.  Using `count` to keep track of where you are in the task, after 10 iterations, you may cancel the timer.

As @Jug6ernaut mentioned, ensure your task won't take long to execute.  Lengthy tasks (ones that take longer than 100 milliseconds, in your case) will cause lag/potentially undesirable results.

Answer (score 3):

```
Handler h = new Handler();
int count = 0;
int delay = 100;//milli seconds
long now = 0;

h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

    public void run(){
        now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //do something

        if(10>count++)
        h.postAtTime(this, now + delay);
    },
delay};
```

Please note that your operation MUST take less then 100ms to execute or it will not be able to run every 100ms, this will be the case for all methods.

Comment: @Mike Gates and your solutions are both correct. 
Is there any difference between which one I use? Because I am having a bit of a dilema of choosing the answer here...

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, if you want to do any UI work(interacting with views) you would need to use my method. If its not UI based @Mike Gates solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to test this right now, but this should work

This is one way:

- Your methods you want to call from here will probably need to be static
- This class can be nested in another class
- You could use % (modulus) so the timer can keep counting up and you can set things to happen at more intervals

create this timer:

```
private Timer mTimer = new Timer();
```

to start this timer:

```
mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), 0, 100L);
```

the timer class:

```
    /**
     * Nested timer to call the task
     */
    private class MyTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                counter++;
                //call your method that you want to do every 100ms
                            if (counter == 10) {
                               counter = 0;
                               //call method you wanted every 1000ms
                            }
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Throwable t) { 
                //handle this  - maybe by starting it back up again            
            }
        }       
    }
```